# Multiple Column results from the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Having a total brain melt today, so apologies if this is so simple its laughable.

Basically I have a Sales table that lists sales values, customers ID, the calendar year and month the Branch ID amongst others.

I need to have a query that lists the top 100 sales, for 2011 and their 2012 sales

I have the 2011 - easy (see below)

```
select top 100 
    C.Name as [Customer],
    SUM (S.SalesTotal) as [Sales for the Year 2011]
from 
    Sales S
Left Join 
    CustomerName C with (NOLOCK) on C.CustomerID = S.CustomerID
where 
    S.Year = '2011' and S.BranchID = 10
Group By 
    C.Name
```

But I need to bring in the sales for 2012 in a separate column alongside the 2011 Sales. On the year column in the table they are just labelled according to the year, so it would be extracting just 2012 for the next column.

I hope that makes sense

Comment: @sgeddes, sorry, my wrong, will remove. (Read C not S... busy doing other stuff at the same time...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it is to use a CASE statement in your sum:

```
select top 100 
C.Name as [Customer],
SUM (CASE WHEN S.Year='2011' THEN S.SalesTotal ELSE 0) as [Sales for the Year 2011]
SUM (CASE WHEN S.Year='2012' THEN S.SalesTotal ELSE 0) as [Sales for the Year 2012]
SUM (CASE WHEN S.Year='2013' THEN S.SalesTotal ELSE 0) as [Sales for the Year 2013]
from Sales S
Left Join CustomerName C with (NOLOCK) on C.CustomerID=S.CustomerID
where S.BranchID=10
Group By C.Name
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to change your filter to include 2012, and use a case statement for your sums:

```
 select top 100 
    C.Name as [Customer],
    SUM (case when year '2011' then S.SalesTotal else 0 end) as [Sales for the Year 2011],
SUM (case when year '2012' then S.SalesTotal else 0 end) as [Sales for the Year 2012]
    from Sales S
    Left Join CustomerName C with (NOLOCK) on C.CustomerID=S.CustomerID
    where S.Year in ('2011','2012' and S.BranchID=10
    Group By C.Name
```

Comment: Fantastic, thanks @Andrew and @D Stanley, as soon as I saw the case it pinged back - I cannot upvote yet I'm afriad